# The module property is undefined when using vm.runInThisContext

Tags: node.js, jasmine, jasmine-node

Here is a function from jasmine 2.0.0 standalone project:

```
function getJasmineRequireObj() {
    if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
        return exports;
    } else {
        window.jasmineRequire = window.jasmineRequire || {};
        return window.jasmineRequire;
    }
}
```

I guess that if I would use the standard require method the module property will be define.
When I load this file using the VM module as follows the module global property is undefined:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');
var jasmineFile = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/jasmine.js');
vm.runInThisContext(src, jasmineFile);
```

Is this the expected behavior of the VM module or a defect?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour. Your code is evaluated in the same context, but not in the same scope, so `module`, `exports` and whatnot are undefined. You can do something like this:

```
var m = require('module')
var src = 'module.exports = 42'
var res = require('vm').runInThisContext(m.wrap(src))(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname)
console.log(module.exports)
```

but there is no much point in doing that, because it's basically what `require` does

Comment: So why would someone use the runInConext method if it makes life difficult?

Comment: `runInThisContext` is used as a stable alternative to `eval`, plus it allows setting file name. I don't think it is really useful, but is used in node core, so why not expose it?

Comment: yeah, if I do this, I get things like "console" is not defined.

Comment: I will tell you a valid usecase at present the esm loader of nodejs don't supports import from url with this i can easy use this to extend it with fetch runInthisContext